# How to achieve NSToolbar with custom dark NSOutlineView like in Tweetbot, Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, nsoutlineview, nstoolbar

I was wondering, how can you achieve a similar effect they have in there:

I am talking about:

A. Either it is done so that they they are drawing the toolbar with a different color under black view.

B. The second option would be simply to limit the size of that toolbar so that it does not reach the black view.

C. Third option would be to draw hide the toolbar and have those icons statically placed into some position.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Note that I would prefer that position of those icons can be customized later on.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [tapbots.com](https://tapbots.com/tweetbot/mac/img/interface.png))</sub>